# Run JavaScript using URL parameters before Page load complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

I have been searching for this for hours, found many ways but no idea why doesn't any of them works..

code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <label id="res"></label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    function crypt() {
        var ex = getParameterByName('eX');
        var er = getParameterByName('eR');
        var aaa = Aes.Ctr.encrypt(ex, er, 256)
        document.write(aaa);
        document.getElementById('res').innerHTML = aaa;
    }
    window.onpaint = crypt();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

What i'm trying to do is to read params from the URL and then run some JavaScript code using these params, then print result in the page.

tried to put the JS code in head, tried onload event, tried addeventlistner, and other stuff, still no luck(on HTML and ASP).
all works after page load completes.

but it must be done before page loads completely..

Thanks.

Comment: you can see how parameters are accessed in javascript here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Comment: Wow, classic ASP...Jesus this still exists :) I'm not clear what bit your stuck on?

Comment: i have no problems with getting params from the URL, the problem is that the JS executes after page load completes..

Comment: If it's classic asp couldn't you use the request object, eg `var ex = <%= Request.Querystring("eX") %>');`

Comment: @John 
 
i have no problems with getting params from the URL, the problem is that the JS executes after page load completes..

Comment: You could try using `<script type="text/javascript" runat="server">`. Classic ASP supports JS as well as VBS, and as your code is rendered on the server it has to run before the page loads.

Comment: that turned all JS code to errors, no idea why.. anyway now i'm trying to do it with just a HTML page..

Comment: any help with HTML page ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.onreadystatechange` event that will be executed just before `document.onload` will execute

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(e)
{
    if (document.readyState === 'complete')
    {
        //Here you may write your code, after this document.load will fire
    }
};
```